# How does Switcheroo affect equipment and Unsummon?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I had a Creature equipped with [Bladed Bracers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239965) and my opponent pulled out [Switcheroo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253704) against my equipped creature.

My Questions are:
1. Does he also get the Bladed Bracers with my creature since the creature was equipped with it?
2. If the answer to the above is yes, does my opponent keep the Bladed Bracers if I played [Unsummon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=265715)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bladed bracers remain attached to the creature and will continue to confer the bonus as long as they remain attached, but you are still their controller.  Next time you have an opportunity you could use the equip ability to move them to another creature you control.  (Note there is no "unequip."  You need to have another creature under your control to move them on to in order to activate the ability.  In this case it's likely you do since you got one from Switcheroo!)

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It makes sense, I just wish I knew that before I lost lol. He gave me a non-flying defender with the switcheroo :(

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Does he also get the Bladed Bracers with my creature since the creature was equipped with it?

No, He does not gain control of the Bladed Bracers. Since you still control the Bracers, you could use their Equip ability to attach them to a creature you control. (Of course, you'll have to wait until you have the mana, and for the stack to be empty in a main phase of one of your turns.)

However, until you reattach the Bracers to another creature, they do remain attached to the stolen creature, and the stolen creature will continue to get the benefits of the Bracers (+1/+1 and possibly vigilance).

> 2. If the answer to the above is yes, does my opponent keep the Bladed Bracers if I played Unsummon?

Not applicable. They never left your control.